# How do I detect if elements being loaded by load() have finished loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I am trying to load some elements from another page under my site, and I did.
But I also tried to apply some jquery action to the elements being loaded.
But, the scripts that I wrote for them are being skipped because they run before the elements are loaded.
Any idea how to detect if the element loading is complete?
(Maybe it is a stupid question, but I really cant find an answer).

This is how I load my elements:

```
$('#homeCat2').load('category.php?id_category=2 #product_list');
```

I tried something like this, but it was no use:

```
$('#homeCat2').load('category.php?id_category=2 #product_list',whenCompleteLoad());

function whenCompleteLoad(){
    var itemNum = $('.ajax_block_product').length;
    alert(itemNum);
};
```

I also tried to put the code for those elements in to the $(document).ready();
but, no luck....

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the *output* of `whenCompleteLoad()` to the callback slot of your `.load()` function. This happens because when you add the parentheses, you call the function.

Removing the parentheses references the actual function, which is what you want:

```
$('#homeCat2').load('category.php?id_category=2 #product_list',whenCompleteLoad);
```

Or you can use an anonymous function (I prefer this method):

```
$('#homeCat2').load('category.php?id_category=2 #product_list', function() {
  var itemNum = $('.ajax_block_product').length;
  alert(itemNum);
});
```

Comment: !!!!Blender you really made my day! I didn't know there is such a difference. Thank you very much! Now it works like a charm:)

Comment: No problem! You have no idea how many times I had this happen to me :P

Comment: Blender I didn't use your 2nd recommended way since i have several set's of elements to be loaded... but thanks:)

Comment: You can probably make a general solution that encompasses *all* of your elements, but that is only nice if you have a bunch of them.

Comment: haha, yeah man. it's so nice to have such a place to hand out with

Comment: i got them about 5 sets... hmm,.. i really don't want my code look so heavy with all the repeating functions..